# Execute function by using evil-set-register

Tags: evil, keyboard-macros

I use evil and I want to execute a function by using Emacs macro system.

Let's say I have the following macro.

```lisp
(evil-set-register ?f [?i ?f ?o ?o ?b ?a ?r escape])
```

I can run the macro by using `@f`. But this system is not easy to read and maintain.

## Question

How to execute an interactive function by using `@f` shortcut?

### Example

Here's function `insert-foobar` which inserts string `foobar`:

```lisp
(defun insert-foobar nil
  "Insert foobar."
  (interactive)
  (call-interactively 'evil-append)
  (insert "foobar")
  (evil-normal-state))
```

```lisp
(evil-set-register ?f (call-interactively 'insert-foobar)) ;; This does not work
(evil-set-register ?f (insert-foobar)) ;; This does not work too
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(evil-set-register ?f (lambda nil "documentation"
                        (call-interactively 'insert-foobar)))
```